# terraform dynamicly attach subnetwork with dynamic nat_ip

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

This is an example of my code
What I need ? - I need network interfaces to dynamically connect to the instance, but only one interface should have an external address (nat_ip = ...)

```
dynamic "network_interface" {
  for_each = var.server_network
  content {
    subnetwork = network_interface.value["subnetwork_name"]
    dynamic "access_config" {
      HERE i need expression like: if nat_ip is true then do create access_config
if false access_config = omit
      for_each = var.server_network.value["nat_ip"]
      content {
        nat_ip = google_compute_address.static_ip.address
      }
    }
  }
}
```

inputs in module:

```
module "vps-test" {
  source             = "../module"
 ......
  server_network = {
    common_network = {
      subnetwork_name = (data.terraform_remote_state.network.outputs.subnetwork_vpc_production_common_name)
      nat_ip = true
      },
    custom_network = {
      subnetwork_name = "10.10.0.1/24"
      nat_ip = false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to explain what's wrong with the current code. Any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the ternary expression [1]:

```
    dynamic "access_config" {
      for_each = network_interface.value.nat_ip ? [1] : []
      content {
        nat_ip = google_compute_address.static_ip.address
      }
    }
```

The ternary expression evaluates the condition (left most part) which is `network_interface.value.nat_ip` in this case. Since it is already a `bool` value, there is no need to compare it to another value, which you would have to do if it were `string` or `number` type.

The condition can evaluate to `true` or `false`. If it evaluates to `true`, the part after the `?` will be assigned to the argument. If it evaluates to `false`, the part after `:` will be assigned to the argument.

The `for_each` will be used for exactly one element (`[1]` in this case) if the ternary operator evaluates to `true` or for none (i.e., it will not be used) if it evaluates to `false`. In the latter case, that means that there will be no `nat_ip`. In the former, that means there will be a `nat_ip` argument defined with the value coming from the resource attribute reference: `google_compute_address.static_ip.address`.

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/conditionals

Comment: can you explain what does it mean?

Comment: add your expression and seems like it works, but have error `Error: Error waiting for instance to create: Networks must be distinct for NICs attached to a VM`

Comment: Well, that's a different question compared to the original one, so please ask another one.